# How to access object after successful RestKit mapping

Tags: ios, singleton, global-variables, restkit

I now have successful object mapping after following the [RestKit documentation here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping). Wahoo! My question now is how do I access this object throughout my project? I used RestKit to map a JSON response to an APIUser object. On the next screen, for example, I want to grab the user's first name from the APIUser object to say hello. How can I access that object?

I'm new to objective-c, so this is probably more a question about use of *global objects*, *singleton classes*, and *persisting data across classes* **in Objective-C** than it is about the RestKit framework.

Posted here are my restkit object mapping logs, in case it helps to reference it. Thanks.  Any help is appreciated.

```
2012-07-30 14:54:04.813 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:240 Performing object mapping sourceObject: {
    apiUser =     {
        active = 1;
        apiUserIdx = 101;
        birthdate = "1980-06-21T00:00:00-06:00";
        countryCode = US;
        firstName = "test_user1_firstname";
        lastName = "test_user1_lastname";
        ssn = 1111;
        userName = "test_user1";
        verified = 1;
    };
}
 and targetObject: (null)
2012-07-30 14:54:04.813 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:254 Examining keyPath 'errors' for mappable content...
2012-07-30 14:54:04.813 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:264 Found unmappable value at keyPath: errors
2012-07-30 14:54:04.814 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:254 Examining keyPath 'apiUser' for mappable content...
2012-07-30 14:54:04.814 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:283 Found mappable data at keyPath 'apiUser': {
    active = 1;
    apiUserIdx = 101;
    birthdate = "1980-06-21T00:00:00-06:00";
    countryCode = US;
    firstName = "test_user1_firstname";
    lastName = "test_user1_lastname";
    ssn = 1111;
    userName = "test_user1";
    verified = 1;
}
2012-07-30 14:54:04.814 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:189 Asked to map source object {
    active = 1;
    apiUserIdx = 101;
    birthdate = "1980-06-21T00:00:00-06:00";
    countryCode = US;
    firstName = "test_user1_firstname";
    lastName = "test_user1_lastname";
    ssn = 1111;
    userName = "test_user1";
    verified = 1;
} with mapping RKObjectMapping class => APIUser: keyPath mappings => (
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: lastName => lastName",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: birthdate => birthdate",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: countryCode => countryCode",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: firstName => firstName",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: password => password",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: apiUserIdx => apiUserIdx",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: active => active",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: userName => userName",
    "RKObjectKeyPathMapping: verified => verified"
)
2012-07-30 14:54:04.815 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:428 Starting mapping operation...
2012-07-30 14:54:04.816 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:242 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'lastName' to 'lastName'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.816 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectPropertyInspector.m:95 Cached property names and types for Class 'APIUser': {
    accessibilityHint = NSString;
    accessibilityLabel = NSString;
    accessibilityLanguage = NSString;
    accessibilityValue = NSString;
    birthdate = NSDate;
    countryCode = NSString;
    firstName = NSString;
    lastName = NSString;
    password = NSString;
    userName = NSString;
}
2012-07-30 14:54:04.818 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:252 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'lastName' to 'lastName'. Value: test_user1_lastname
2012-07-30 14:54:04.818 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:242 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'birthdate' to 'birthdate'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.818 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:115 Found transformable value at keyPath 'birthdate'. Transforming from type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDate'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.818 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:97 Transforming string value '1980-06-21T00:00:00-06:00' to NSDate...
2012-07-30 14:54:04.819 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:259 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'birthdate to keyPath 'birthdate' -- value is unchanged ((null))
2012-07-30 14:54:04.821 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:242 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'countryCode' to 'countryCode'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.822 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:252 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'countryCode' to 'countryCode'. Value: US
2012-07-30 14:54:04.822 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:242 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'firstName' to 'firstName'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.822 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:252 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'firstName' to 'firstName'. Value: test_user1_firstname
2012-07-30 14:54:04.822 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:291 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'password'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.823 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:242 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'apiUserIdx' to 'apiUserIdx'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.839 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:252 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'apiUserIdx' to 'apiUserIdx'. Value: 101
2012-07-30 14:54:04.840 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:242 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'active' to 'active'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.840 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:252 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'active' to 'active'. Value: 1
2012-07-30 14:54:04.840 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:242 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'userName' to 'userName'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.840 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:252 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'userName' to 'userName'. Value: test_user1
2012-07-30 14:54:04.841 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:242 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'verified' to 'verified'
2012-07-30 14:54:04.845 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:252 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'verified' to 'verified'. Value: 1
2012-07-30 14:54:04.845 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:434 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2012-07-30 14:54:04.846 TestApp[2361:1a707] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:254 Examining keyPath 'error' for mappable content...
2012-07-30 14:54:04.846 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:264 Found unmappable value at keyPath: error
2012-07-30 14:54:04.846 TestApp[2361:1a707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:304 Finished performing object mapping. Results: {
    apiUser = "<APIUser: 0xcd8b170>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I needed to create a new instance of APIUser and set it equal to `[objects objectAtIndex:0].`  As in:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {

    NSLog(@"There are %i objects.", objects.count);

    APIUser *apiUser = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Loaded apiUserIdx #%i -> First name: %@, Last name: %@", apiUser.apiUserIdx, apiUser.firstName, apiUser.lastName);

}
```